# Security group in LDAP connection string

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I've the following structure in my Active Directory

```
i.MyDomain.dk
    MyOrganizationalUnit
        MySecurityGroup
```

I only want users in the security group (MySecurityGroup) to have access to a website. My LDAP connection string looks like this:

```
LDAP://i.MyDomain.dk/OU=MySecurityGroup, OU=MyOrganizationalUnit, DC=i, DC=MyDomain, DC=dk
```

This is not working because MySecurityGroup is not an OU.

Is it possible to include a security group in the LDAP connection string? If so, how should the LDAP connection string look like?

Comment: What is the WEBSite running on? (Apache, ??)

Comment: It's an ASP.NET MVC website.